# When trying to run lettuce scenario with examples, the steps I have created fail to be recognized

Tags: python, continuous-integration, lettuce

Let me see if I can show you how confused I am.

If I just use a lettuce features file with variables inline, everything works.  For example, if I create the following feature file:

```
Feature: File Finder
    I need to just look for the presence of certain files on a system

Scenario Outline:  Verify the presence (or absence) of a file on a system
    Given I log into a system at "172.16.100.23" as user "cadmin" with password "cadmin"
    Then I can look for "/var/log/nginx.log" and know that it should "not" be there
```

And run lettuce against it, it tells me to create the following steps:

```
You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from lettuce import step

@step(u'Given I log into a system at "([^"]*)" as user "([^"]*)" with password "([^"]*)"')
def given_i_log_into_a_system_at_group1_as_user_group2_with_password_group2(step, group1, group2, group3):
    assert False, 'This step must be implemented'
@step(u'Then I can look for "([^"]*)" and know that it should "([^"]*)" be there')
def then_i_can_look_for_group1_and_know_that_it_should_group2_be_there(step, group1, group2):
    assert False, 'This step must be implemented'
```

If I paste that header ("from lettuce import step") and those steps into a filefinder.py folder and change "assert False" to "assert True" to just make the tests pass, I pass with flying colors:

```
Feature: File Finder
  I need to just look for the presence of certain files on a system

Scenario: Verify the presence (or absence) of a file on a system
  Given I log into a system at "172.16.100.23" as user "cadmin" with password "cadmin"
  Then I can look for "/var/log/nginx.log" and know that it should "not" be there

1 feature (1 passed)
1 scenario (1 passed)
2 steps (2 passed)
```

Now, I want to add an Examples table to the mix.  All I do is add `Then I can ask <manager> for <item>` as my third step and the following Examples table:

```
Examples:
    | manager   | item            |
    | "bob"     | "raise"         |
    | "suzy"    | "more switches" |
    | "bill"    | "more coffee"   |
```

When I run lettuce against this, it tells me:

```
You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from lettuce import step

@step(u'Then I can ask <manager> for <item>')
def then_i_can_ask_manager_for_item(step):
    assert False, 'This step must be implemented'
```

So, I add that to my filefinder.py file and change "assert False" to "assert True" just to get it to pass and see green colors on my console.  If I run lettuce against that, it gives me the exact same response, as if it doesn't recognize the placeholders `<manager>` and `<item>` as creating a valid step, I guess.  That's the only time I can't create the step that it asks for - when I'm using placeholders as described here: http://lettuce.it/tutorial/scenario-outlines.html  It's odd that the example shows "Scenario Outline: Factorials [0-4]" because I can't tell if the [0-4] is needed or not.  It doesn't seem to make a difference at all in my tests, although I don't have any successful tests with examples so I could be totally wrong.

What I need to do is figure out why lettuce doesn't see those steps which have the "`<placeholder>`" syntax inline.

Can somebody shed some light on this for me?

Answer (score 4):

I came across this page: http://lettuce.it/intro/wtf.html appropriately named wtf!

What I need to do is put quotes around the `<placeholders>` and remove the quotes in the Examples table.

Now, my features file looks like:

```
Feature: File Finder
    I need to just look for the presence of certain files on a system

Scenario Outline:  Verify the presence of a file on a system [0-3]
    Given I log into a system at "172.16.100.23" as user "cadmin" with password "cadmin"
    Then I can look for "/var/log/nginx.log" and know that it should "not" be there
    Then I can ask "<manager>" for "<item>"

Examples:
    | manager | item          |
    | bob     | raise         |       
    | suzy    | more switches |
    | bill    | more coffee   |
```

And it passes with all sorts of green colors on my console:

```
Feature: File Finder
  I need to just look for the presence of certain files on a system

Scenario Outline: Verify the presence of a file on a system
  Given I log into a system at "172.16.100.23" as user "cadmin" with password "cadmin"
  Then I can look for "/var/log/nginx.log" and know that it should "not" be there
  Then I can ask "<manager>" for "<item>"

Examples:
  | manager | item          |
  | bob     | raise         |
  | suzy    | more switches |
  | bill    | more coffee   |

1 feature (1 passed)
3 scenarios (3 passed)
9 steps (9 passed)
```

The take-away...the "[0-4]" is not necessary and when using Examples, make sure you use "Scenario Outline" rather than "Scenario".